# вывод слова наоборот

Tags: c, gcc, strlen

задача следующая: надо спросить слово с пользователя и вывести его на экран наоборот. когда использую такой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char str[40];
    printf("enter word\n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    for (size_t i = strlen(str); i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

то на выходе получаю десять строк разнообразных символов. и в конце поялвяется такая надпись "14904 segmentation fault (core dumped)"
когда использую такой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char str[40];
    printf("enter word\n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    for (size_t i = strlen(str); i > 0; i--) {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

то получаю все кроме первого символа.

Comment: и ещё, а зачем вы 0-символ пытаетесь выводить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

size_t имеет беззнаковый тип, поэтому ваш цикл никогда не завершается в первом случае. После достижения нуля, переменной i присваивается наибольшее для типа значение. Запрос по такому большому адресу и вызывает segmentation fault. Во втором случае вы останавливаетесь на нуле. При этом при нулевом значении i тело цикла не выполняется и первый символ не выводится. Попробуйте заменить тип i на int. И начинать цикл нужно не с strlen(str), а c strlen(str)-1, потому что strlen(str) - это символ конца строки и его явно выводить не нужно. Например вот так все будет работать:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char str[40];
    printf("enter word\n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    for (int i = strlen(str)-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас 2 неприятности.
1. Вы используете беззнаковый тип в проверке `i >= 0`, а он всегда не меньше 0.
2. Последний символ слова имеет индекс `strlen(str)-1`, а не `strlen(str)`.

Сделайте так - добавьте только 2 символа (`-1`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char str[40];
    printf("enter word\n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    for (size_t i = strlen(str); i > 0; i--) {
        printf("%c", str[i-1]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```